# Android Character Map are Not Save

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing this statement in android `tv.settext("√"+value +" = "+result);` e.g 
`tv.settext("√3=17321");` the final result is look like **√3=17321** but when i save or run my program it show me this error . I don't know how to post image but i writing error in commas""

```
"Save coult not be completed. Try File>Save As...if the problem persists.
    Reason :
    Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp 1252" character encoding. 
    Either change the encoding or remove the character which are not 
    supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding".

Button(1)Text=OK    Button(2)Text=Save as UTF-8   Button(3)Text=Select First Character
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit

The answer is just click on  Save as UTF-8 button it not create problem in your program .